# Adicionar troca de conteúdo automatica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso encontrar uma forma de trocar as informações data-id e data-content para .number e .passo automaticamente, sem ter que depender do hover().

Preciso manter tanto a forma automática dessa troca como se fosse uma apresentação e o hover() se caso o usuário quiser permanecer na visualização de uma informação especifica.

Creio que fui claro

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav-metodologia img').hover(function(){
        var getID      = $(this).data('id');
        var getContent = $(this).data('content');

        $('.number').html(getID);
        $('.passo').html(getContent);

        //console.log(pegaId);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-metodologia pull-right slide-here">
    <img src="images/01.png" data-id="1" data-content="conteudo 01"/>
    <img src="images/02.png" data-id="2" data-content="conteudo 02"/>
    <img src="images/03.png" data-id="3" data-content="conteudo 03"/>
</div><!-- /.nav-metodologia -->

<div class="box-metodologia">
    <div class="number radius-2">1</div>
    <div class="passo">
        <p>Conteúdo inicial</p>
    </div><!-- /.box-metodologia -->
</div><!-- /box-metodologia -->
```

Comment: Pablo, quantas `.number` e `.passo` existem? uma por imagem ou só um de cada? O que quer dizer com automático? => quando a página carrega?

Comment: São 7 de cada, é acontecer a mesma coisa que acontece atualmente mas sem ter de utilizar o hover() primeiro, quando carregar a pagina já começar a rodar de 1 em 1 passo como se a pessoa estivesse passando o mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alternar entre os itens, você pode manter uma variável que indique o próximo item a ser trocado e usar `setInterval` para executar a troca repetidamente e incrementar a variável.

Para interromper a apresentação com o cursor, você pode usar `clearInterval` no evento `mouseover` e `setInterval` novamente no evento `mouseout`, para retomar a apresentação.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/primo_dang/RdBz8/)

<sub>Adaptado [desta pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945056/how-to-stop-jquery-imageslider-on-mouse-hover)</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado Dang, é exatamente isso!